# (a,b,c) are continuous r.v. and c is independent of (a,b). Prove that $P[E(a\mid (b,c)) = E(a\mid b)]=1$

Tags: probability, statistics

I've been stuck with this question for a while, I know that I need to prove $E(a|(b,c)) = E(a|b)$ then if I take the probability of it, it becomes 1 but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

We prove it by definition. Note $E(a|b)$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(b,c)$, i.e., the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $(b,c)$, it suffices to show for any set $A\in \sigma(b,c)$, we have 
$$\int_A E(a|b)\,dP=\int_A a\,dP.$$
By $\pi-\lambda$ theorem, it suffices to establish the identity for the generating sets, hence we assume $A=\{b\in B_1, c\in B_2\}$ where $B_1,B_2$ are borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$. Denote $A_1=\{b\in B_1\},A_2=\{c\in B_2\}$. Note by assumption $1_{A_2}$ is independent to any random variables measurable with respect to $\sigma(a,b)$.

\begin{align*}
\int_A E(a|b)\,dP&=\int_\Omega E(a|b)1_A\,dP=\int_\Omega E(a|b)1_{A_1}1_{A_2}\,dP\\
&=\int_\Omega E(a|b)1_{A_1}dP\int_\Omega 1_{A_2}\,dP\\
&=\int_\Omega a1_{A_1}dP\int_\Omega 1_{A_2}\,dP=\int_\Omega a1_{A_1}1_{A_2}\,dP\\
&=\int_A a\,dP.
\end{align*}

Comment: Just a brief remark:
John ZHANG's solution is the way you usually handle conditional expectations:
you "guess" the solution and show that it has the defining properties of the conditional expectations. 
With this technique you can also prove linearity, towerproperty, etc. of conditional expectations.